# Error in update query: Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to run a simple update query but it throws the following error on line 5

```
update t3
set t3.Act_Flg = 'N', t3.ActiveEndDate = getdate()
from dbo.STG_EmployeeMaster_TEMP t3 
inner join dbo.TEMP_EmployeeMaster t1 on t3.GPN = t1.GPN, t3.Name = t1.Name
where t1.RecordChangedFlag = 'Y'
```

It is throwing an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '='.

I am not getting where is mistake?

Comment: `join` on two conditions should use `and` instead of `,` to separate

Comment: "Not sure why its not liking the comma" - because it's not the right syntax - use `AND` instead,

Comment: `join` conditions must simplify down to a boolean true (include the joined records) or false (exclude the records). exactly how should `t3.gpn=t1.tpn, t3.name=t1.name` be evaluated? what does `true,false` work out to be?

Comment: @xbb - either `and` or `or` depending on intent, anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AND.

```
update t3
set t3.Act_Flg='N', t3.ActiveEndDate=getdate()
from dbo.STG_EmployeeMaster_TEMP t3 INNER join dbo.TEMP_EmployeeMaster t1
on t3.GPN=t1.GPN and
t3.Name = t1.Name
where t1.RecordChangedFlag='Y'
```